# How do I make sure that the parent state is also updated when child state is updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, ref

I have a architecture of a React application as follows:

```
<GrandParentComponent>
    <ParentComponent>
        <ChildComponent>
    </ParentComponent>
</GrandParentComponent>
```

The child component is creating a context within itself to be shared with all its internal components.
I have a `ref` being passed as a `useCallback()` from the `<ParentComponent>` to the `<ChildComponent>` to keep track of a state which is being passed from the `<GrandparentComponent>`.

**GrandParent**

```
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

return (
    <>
        { isPlaying ? "True" : "False" } 
        <ParentComponent {...{isPlaying, setIsPlaying}}/>
    </>
    );
```

**Parent**

```
    const [button, setButton] = useState();

    const handleRef = useCallback( current => {
        if(current) {
            setButton(current.button);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(button) {
            const callback = ({type}) => setIsPlaying(type === "play");
            button.addEventListener("play", callback);
            return () => {
                button.removeEventListener("play", callback);
            };
        }
    }, [button]);

return (
        { isPlaying ? "True" : "False" } 
    <ChildRoot>
        <Child ref={handleRef}/>
    </ChildRoot>
);
```

**Child**

```
const export ChildRoot = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <ChildContext.Provider value={{
            isOpen: true,
            setIsOpen: () => {}
            }}
        />
            {children}
        </ChildContext.Provider>
    );
};


const export Child = ({}, forwardRef) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    
    useImperativeHandle(forwardRef, () => ({
        get button() {
           return ref.current();
        }
    })
});
```

For some reason the value of `isPlaying` is only reflected in the `<ParentComponent>` but not in the `<GrandParentComponent>`. I've tried using a `useContext()` and that hasn't solved this either.

How do I make sure that the state is consistent?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by combining both the `Child` components into one component, and exporting it to the `Parent` component.